# How to combine two init function?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on speeding up my page loading speed. I have these two defers script to minimize loading time and improve performance.

The problem is only the last function will work. ex. if 'imgDefer' is in the last, only image will load on the front page. The same as 'vidDefer' if in last, only video will load and the image will not

I don't know how to combine these two init(). I'm not good at javascript.
These are the codes: (I place these codes in footer area)

**video**

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx"></iframe>
```

**image**

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="imagesrource" alt="">
```

**Video script**

```
function init() {
    var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var s = 0; s < vidDefer.length; s++) {
        if(vidDefer[s].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            vidDefer[s].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[s].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

**Image Script**

```
function init() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName("img-responsive");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
          imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Why not just put all the code in the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically what it sounds like is that you'd like to be able to run multiple functions when the `window.onload` event gets triggered.

You could create two separate functions, like so:

```js
function runVideoScript() {
  var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
  // ...
}

function runImageScript() {
  var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName('img-responsive')
  // ...
}
```

Then you can create an `init` function. This way, both functions will be called from the `init` function, and `init` will be called when `window.onload` gets triggered:

```js
function init() {
  runVideoScript()
  runImageScript()
}

window.onload = init
```

---

In your current setup, the reason why only the last function gets called is because you're replacing `window.onload` with another function, and basically disregarding the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Just make one init function which will be for example initVideo function and after it's executed run initImage.

```
function initVideo() {
        var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var s = 0; s < vidDefer.length; s++) {
            if(vidDefer[s].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                vidDefer[s].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[s].getAttribute('data-src'));
            }
        }
        initImage();
    }
    function initImage() {
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName("img-responsive");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
            if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
              imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = initVideo();
```